# vim ruby plugin indentation

Tags: ruby, vim

I have recently set up [`vim-ruby`](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) plugin and expected it to work out of the box as the [docs](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport) are saying, however not even the basic ruby indentation is working for me. I've a pretty simple vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible           " turn vi into vim
filetype off               " required by vundle
" VUNDLE SETUP
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()          " required
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" Track the engine.
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
" " Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" go-vim plugin by fatih
Plugin 'fatih/vim-go'

" vim-ruby plugin for ruby shit
Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'

" vim-fugitive plugin for git
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

" enabled vim-neatstatus line
Plugin 'maciakl/vim-neatstatus'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " enable file detection

syntax on        " Always turn the syntax on
set expandtab    " Turn tab into spaces
set number       " Turn on numbering of lines
set showmatch    " Show matching brackets.
set matchtime=5  " Bracket blinking.
set noshowmode   " Shows vim mode

" set status line
set laststatus=2 " Always show status line.

" Match and search
set hlsearch    " highlight search
set ignorecase  " Do case in sensitive matching with
set smartcase   " be sensitive when there's a capital letter
set incsearch   " Search incrementally

" color scheme
set background=dark
colorscheme molokai
set t_Co=256

let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" remap hjkl
noremap ' l
noremap ; k
noremap l j
noremap k h
nnoremap . ;

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
" Fast quitting
nmap <leader>q :q<cr>
" Fast save and quit
nmap <leader>ww :wq<cr>

" toggle the paste
map <leader>p :set paste!<CR>
" toggles search highlighting
nmap <silent> <leader>n :set hlsearch!<CR>

" Turn off auto-commenting
au FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=cro

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-k>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-c-k>"
```

Nothing crazy. However, whenever editing ruby file (.rb, Rakefile etc., the indentation is always 8 spaces and I've no clue why.

Even the simple if clause turns into this:

```
if foo == "bar"
    puts "foobar"
end
```

vim-ruby does a pretty awesome job detecting ruby files like Rakefile etc., but after spending several hours investigating indentation I gave up and open this issue.

My vim version:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 22 2014 11:49:13)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-430
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing `tabstop = 2` somewhere.  

However, the plugin should be taking care of this for you, if you are expecting it to 'just work'.  I would try removing the tab controls in your vimrc file.  Something seems to be conflicting.  This part is definitely related to your question, so it may be part of the problem.  Comment it, and restart vim, see if you have any change.

See the documentation by reading `:help expandtab` to get on your way to understanding vim settings.

Also note that if you are changing the 'compatible' setting, this setting gets reset.

Comment: setnocompatible is there because vundle plugin needs it. I tried commenting out expandtab, though I had a feeling that was not the problem, but as I expected that did not help. Yeah, I think some of those plugins are stepping on each other's toes or something else is broken.

Comment: Yeah, actually you will want nocompatible, as it gives you the new 'vim' capabilities.  Sorry I don't have a right out answer for you though.  I would suggest checking the issues on the repositories where these plugins are hosted.  I [suspect you have](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/234) though. :)

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins, and adding them in one by one, until one breaks the plugin that you expect to "work out of the box"?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that and only kept Vundle and vim-ruby. That did not help either.I've also removed ALL the settings. Looks like vim-ruby is borking the config somewhere.

Comment: Try to add autocmd FileType ruby set shiftwidth=2 to .vimrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `autocmd FileType ruby set shiftwidth=2` to `.vimrc`